# Random Sampling with VBA to match criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a project, that involves randomly picking id's and tagging them yes ot no.
Based on these criteria

1. the benchmark is 8%, which means the cases tagged as yes should be 8%
2. for each of the persons processed the id's should be 8% individually.
   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand instruction 2. You could possibly play around with this code.

```
Sub TagYesNo()

'I am assuming your ids are in column A and you have 1000 of them.
For A = 2 To 1001
    If Rnd() > 0.92 Then
        Range("B" & A).Value = "Yes"
    Else
        Range("B" & A).Value = "No"
    End If
Next A
```

Comment: If my response helped then please up vote my answer.

Comment: Hi Ross, the question was i have a data set of 1000 for example. Out of the 1000 i want to random sample 8% of the total 1000 i.e 80 out of the 1000. and also out of 1000  there are people who process those 1000 numbers so every person should also follow 8%. thank you